# How to await multiple calls of the same function with different params in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

How can I await multiple calls of the same function with different params in Javascript?

I am aware of `Promise.All([func1, func2, func 3 ...])` however I am essentially calling a function `getRecipes(ingredients)` from a "for loop" with different 'ingredients' being passed into `getRecipes()` each time. I can't pass an array of `[getRecipes,getRecipes,getRecipes]` into `Promise.All()` because I need to pass different params every time.

So how should I go about waiting for all of the `getRecipes()` results to be returned and then processing once they are all completed? I don't know the number of `getRecipes` requests since its dynamically called based on the "for loop".

Sample Code: `

```
           const newAnnotatedList = []
           const ingredientList = []
          
            for(var i = 0; i < listOfPictures.length; i++) {
              const ingredients =  runClarifai(listOfPictures[i].uri)
              ingredientList.push(ingredients)
            }
            console.log('Starting to wait')
           Promise.all(ingredientList).then((result) => console.log('Done Waiting'));
           for(var i = 0; i < listOfPictures.length; i++) {
            const ingredients =  ingredientList[i]
            // ingredientList.push(ingredients)

            newAnnotatedList.push({id:listOfPictures[i].id ,uri:listOfPictures[i].uri, ingredients: ingredients})
          }
           `
```

When I `console.log(ingredientsList[0])` for example, I'm not returned the value of the promise (the array of ingredient strings) but instead:

```
Promise {
  "_40": 1,
  "_55": null,
  "_65": 0,
  "_72": Handler {
    "onFulfilled": [Function anonymous],
    "onRejected": [Function anonymous],
    "promise": Promise {
      "_40": 0,
      "_55": null,
      "_65": 0,
      "_72": null,
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: please format the code in the question above so it is easier to read

Comment: "I can't pass an array of [getRecipes,getRecipes,getRecipes] into Promise.All()" --> Why not? If `getRecipes` return a Promise, you can call it with whatever you want and get back a different Promise every time

Comment: I think this is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55860585/how-to-use-nodemailer-in-nodejs-for-bulk-data-sending/

Comment: You've edited this since I've answered and your code looks a lot like my code.  Are you simply confused as to why the "starting" and "done" console logs are occurring out of order from the results?  Because that is how async code works-- if you want to await the result you need to leverage [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: @AlexanderNied Ah i think that was tripping me out initially, but I took your suggestion to move the "done" to the Promise.all().then() function. I'm still confused about why the value stored in the promise array isn't what the promises evaluate to?

Comment: For some strange reason, the value returned by the promise is under "_55" so I simply did ingredientsList[i]._55 to access it

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want to do is first iterate through however many calls to `getRecipes` are required, and store the returned Promises in an array.  Only once you have finished iterating through your loop, making all the required calls and pushing them to the array do you then pass that array to `Promise.all()`:

```js
function getRecipes(i) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const timeout = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500);
    setTimeout(() => resolve(i), timeout);
  });
}

function callGetRecipesLoop() {
  const randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  console.log(randNum + ' results expected');
  const promisesArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < randNum; i++) {
    promisesArray.push(getRecipes(i));
  }
  Promise.all(promisesArray).then((result) => console.log(result));
}

callGetRecipesLoop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `async` `await` for clean code, such scenarios gets compilcated if we are counting on `.then`

Your problem is here `Promise.all(ingredientList).then((result) => console.log('Done Waiting'));`

`result` in `then` has your values

Solution :

```
const test = async() => {
const arrayOfResult = await Promise.all(ingredientsList.map(ingredient => getrecipies(ingredient)))
console.log(arrayOfResult) // [promise1_result, promise2_result, ...]
}
test()
```

Hope you now have clear idea.